# No matching function for already defined function

Tags: c++, string

i have a code, which I can't compile because of error, that said `"error: no matching function for call to 'asd'"` in the line `if (asd( checkline[i], alphabet)==true)`. I don't know what have i done wrong, because `asd()` is defined before `exname()`. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
const std::string alphabet="йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэёячсмитьбю";
using namespace std;

bool asd(string two, string one)
{
    size_t pos=one.find(two);
    if(pos!= string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

string exname(string checkline)
{
    string newstr;

    for (int i = 0; i < checkline.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (asd( checkline[i], alphabet)==true)
        {
            /* code */
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
```

Comment: A character is not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're treating `char` from `checkline[i]` as string

```
bool asd(string two, string one)
//        ^^^^^ make this char
{
   //.....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler's looking for `bool asd(char, string)`, and you only defined `bool asd(string, string)`.  You need to either modify the definiton of `asd` or change how you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

In this call of the function

```
if (asd( checkline[i], alphabet)==true)
```

the first argument has type `char` while the function is defined such a way that its first parameter has type `std::string`. There is no implicit conversion from an object of type `char` to an object of type `std::string` in class `std::string`.
So the compiler issues the error because it can not find a function with name `asd` that has the first parameter of type `char`..

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter for the function call to the asd function could be changed to char, as suggested previously, **or** the use of checkline could be done by using the **substr** method to create a string which contains only the relevant character. The other changes I made: 1) define const string after "using namespace std", 2) remove unnecessary std:: from the front of the const string, and 3) is int() casting checkline.length() to eliminate an unnecessary warning message:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string alphabet="йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэёячсмитьбю";

bool asd(string two, string one)
{
    size_t pos=one.find(two);
    if(pos != string::npos)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

string exname(string checkline)
{
    string newstr;
    for (int i = 0; i < int(checkline.length()); ++i)
    {
        if (asd( checkline.substr(i, 1), alphabet) == true)
        {
            /* code */
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
```